# How to share uploaded file from ASP.Net core API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have uploaded a file to `wwwroot/images` folder at `.NET core` using Api from `angular 7`.
But now, I am unable to access this file.

I have added this in Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{         
     app.UseStaticFiles();
}
```

and I also added this in Program.cs file:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
     CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
       WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Comment: How do you request it? Link should be like HOST/images/FILE

Comment: @IvMisticos Yes, I am using like that

Comment: Does it happen in development(localhost)?What is the error message?It works well when I use `<img src="https://localhost:5001/images/myfile.png"/>` in html

Comment: @XingZou It happens on server

Comment: make sure that the file exists in images folder.could you show your request and network tag, error message in the question?